# Wordpress admin login in android WebView

Tags: android, wordpress, webview

I am developing an android webview app using java to log in on my WordPress admin panel (mysite.com/wp-admin) but I can't log in. If I input the correct username and password the login page is refreshing and If I input the wrong username/password I am getting an error saying wrong info. I am attaching my code below.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView webView;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout layoutRefresh;
    private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
    public ValueCallback<Uri[]> uploadMessage;
    public static final int REQUEST_SELECT_FILE = 100;
    private final static int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE = 1;

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)
    {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        {
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_SELECT_FILE)
            {
                if (uploadMessage == null)
                    return;
                uploadMessage.onReceiveValue(WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams.parseResult(resultCode, intent));
                uploadMessage = null;
            }
        }
        else if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE)
        {
            if (null == mUploadMessage)
                return;
            // Use MainActivity.RESULT_OK if you're implementing WebView inside Fragment
            // Use RESULT_OK only if you're implementing WebView inside an Activity
            Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != RESULT_OK ? null : intent.getData();
            mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
            mUploadMessage = null;
        }
    }

    //WebActivity view Settings
    private void webViewSettings() {
        //webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        //webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        webSettings.setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
        webSettings.getAllowContentAccess();
        webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
        webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
        webSettings.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
        webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webSettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21){
            webSettings.setMixedContentMode(0);
            webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        }else if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19){
            webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        }else {
            webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        }
        //webSettings.setGeolocationEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webSettings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(webView, true);
            webView.getSettings().setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW);
        } else {
            CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
        }
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
    }
    //Progressbar and network settings
    private void progressBarSettings() {
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {           
            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.swipeLayout,new ErrorFragment());
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                progressBar.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                progressBar.setVisibility(GONE);
            }
        });
    }

    //Alert Dialog on app exit
    private void ExitDialog(){
        final AlertDialog.Builder build = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        build.setMessage("Really want to Exit?"); //Alert message on exit
        build.setCancelable(false);
        build.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        build.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                finish();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alertDialog = build.create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).hide();
        UrlActivity urlActivity = new UrlActivity();
        SharedPreferences urlPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("pref",MODE_PRIVATE);
        final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = urlPreferences.edit();
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if(intent.getStringExtra("url") != null){
            editor.putString("urlData",intent.getStringExtra("url"));
            editor.commit();
        }
        String getUrl = urlPreferences.getString("urlData",urlActivity.home);
        editor.clear().commit();
        layoutRefresh = this.findViewById(R.id.refresh);
        CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);
        CookieSyncManager.getInstance().startSync();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Under Development by Sajeeb",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        layoutRefresh.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                if (webView.getUrl() != null) {
                    webView.reload();
                }
                layoutRefresh.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        });
        webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.loading);
        webView.loadUrl(getUrl);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()
        {
            // For 3.0+ Devices (Start)
            // onActivityResult attached before constructor
            protected void openFileChooser(ValueCallback uploadMsg, String acceptType)
            {
                mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Browser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
            }


            // For Lollipop 5.0+ Devices
            public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView mWebView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback, WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams)
            {
                if (uploadMessage != null) {
                    uploadMessage.onReceiveValue(null);
                    uploadMessage = null;
                }

                uploadMessage = filePathCallback;

                Intent intent = null;
                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    intent = fileChooserParams.createIntent();
                }
                try
                {
                    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_SELECT_FILE);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e)
                {
                    uploadMessage = null;
                    //Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Cannot Open File Chooser", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }

            //For Android 4.1 only
            protected void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture)
            {
                mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "File Browser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
            }

            protected void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg)
            {
                mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
            }
        });
        webViewSettings();
        progressBarSettings();



    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        CookieSyncManager.getInstance().stopSync();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
        } else {
            ExitDialog();
        }
    }
}
```